# Vertical scroll causes swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a strange issue: When I scroll vertically it triggers swipe right/left events.

I've checked it on iOS...

The swipe events are bound to the `data-role='page'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try configuring the `horizontalDistanceThreshold` to a higher value to allow more horizontal movement when scrolling.

Comment: Thank you mate...I just found that yestarday...I'm checkin it out ;-)